# Algorithm for partial point set registration with PCL

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mathematical-optimization, points

I need to perform a registration algorithm between two sets of points A and B. Set A is my source points and set B my traget points.
Point set B has approximately 8671 points and point set A has only 40 points. I need to find the transformation matrix that allows to transform the points from set A to set B with the minimum possible error.
I am using the PCL library, someone can recommend me some algorithm or solution to this problem. I have used the TrimmedICP algorithm but there is no solution, there is no convergence.

I attach the following data to help understand the problem.
An image (Image_points) with the graph of the points of set B.
A file (set_b) with the points of set B.
A file (set_a) with the points of set A.
I also attach the correspondence of the points of set A with the points of set B in order to calculate the exact error of the transformations (In the real process this correspondence is unknown).
[correspondence](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjORW_cHuMAabdZSVgI3AsIvzyw?e=1i8jmy),
[set_a](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjORW_cHuMAabCYeYygYtaeN6LU?e=W00blJ), [set_b](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AjORW_cHuMAabmRwod8VX75hIb4?e=4sXr6B), [image_points](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjORW_cHuMAaa7YEWdbGxyHCHKw?e=QdqaAs)

[Added by Spektre]

Plot of both sets (A green, B blue)

[image: plot]

Comment: at least show plot of your data (and ideally also post sample sets somewhere in txt form so people here can also test) if it can be done with exploiting the shape of your data and also so we see what kind of properties your data have... Usually RANSAC is used for tasks like this when nothing is certain...  If your data has specific geometry properties sometimes PCA and or OOBB can help narrowing the fit

Comment: What sort of 'transformation matrix' is allowed? Just rotation and translation, or something more general?

Comment: The set of points A are extracted from the surface of a 3d object on a computer. That same object is had in the real world with the same dimensions as the virtual object, but only 42 points can be extracted from the real object.
The problem is to find a transformation matrix that allows mapping the points of the object's coordinates in the real world to the coordinates of the virtual object or vice versa.
The transformation must be a rigid transformation..

Comment: without plot and or sample data "no one" will answer ... its similar to DIP/CV each case is different and requires different approach and making generic answer will not fit ... and it would be too much work anyway ... and guess what you have will most likely not lead to solution applicable to you so no one bothers to answer ... as I mentioned plot will show us the properties and sample would allow to directly test without much work if you add both you increase your chance to get valid answer.

Comment: I have shared the necessary data.

Comment: @MiguelSocorro 1. in order to notify user `nick` you need to add `@nick` to the comment and site will do the rest.  2. I tried visualize your sets (added result in your post) and looks like your set A is not matching the set B fully ... looks like the right half might match one of the blue arcs however the whole left side is just noise so you would probably first need to filter out points that does not belong and only than procede to the difference transformation. As ~half of the points are bad the correspondence will be a very hard to find. What do you know about how the points are obtained?

Comment: @MiguelSocorro just tested your correspondence set and its bad ... if the transform is rigid (so no skew or scale, just translation and rotation)  then the set A has much bigger BBOX than set B meaning matched points do not correspond at all ... so using such set will lead to no or wrong results

Comment: however from second look the A sets might be scaled with different factors per axis so not a rigid transform at all ...

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for your answer, after reading your answer and reviewing the data I could see that there were some alterations when obtaining the points. I already fixed those problems and now I can find a solution just by doing rotations and translations. I can see that you have a lot of experience in this area. Could you recommend me a book or article to learn a little more about these topics?

Comment: @MiguelSocorro This is far from my cup of tea and also I obtained my knowledge by 25+ years of coding (mostly 2D/3D/ND gfx,geometry and motion control)  instead of reading books ... so I cant recommend any books for this ... however this task is similar to DIP/CV problems related to 3D reconstruction and or geometry fitting and or feature point matching (where the RANSAC usually is used)